# Iterate a 1D collection of arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

I am representing a collection of arrays as follows:

```
std::vector<int> v = {3, 0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 5, 6 };
```

This array represent a collection of 4 arrays that are `{0,1,2}`, `{3}`, `{4}`, and `{5,6}`. So `v` contains first the size of the array, and then the array contents follow.

I am trying to iterate over the array, i.e. step through every element of each array and process them somehow. If this was say a vector of vectors, one could simply do:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > v;
v.emplace_back(std::vector<int>({ 0, 1, 2 }));
v.emplace_back(std::vector<int>({ 3 }));
v.emplace_back(std::vector<int>({ 4 }));
v.emplace_back(std::vector<int>({ 5, 6 }));

for (std::size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
{
    for (std::size_t j = 0; j < v[i].size(); ++j)
    {
        std::cout << v[i][j] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

But how do I achieve the same with the scheme described first? I feel like I am thinking too hard, and I'm only able to come up with something way too complex. Is there some neat solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution doesn't seem to be much more complicated than it would be for a 2D vector:

```
std::vector<int>::iterator it = std::begin(v);

while (it != std::end(v)) {
    int n = *it;
    for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
        ++it;
        std::cout << *it << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    ++it;
}
```

We just walk `it` through the vector. The variable `n` tells us how many elements we need to print on each line.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the vector already constructed, try iterators!

```
std::vector<int>::iterator i = v.begin();
while(i != v.end()){
    size_t n = *i;
    for(size_t j = 0; j < n; j++)
        std::cout << *(++i) << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    ++i;
}
```